# Git can't have access rights to edit the remote repository

Tags: git, github, gitlab

When I changed my username on github my git bash can't recognize that it is my account so when I try to push changes to my remote repos on github it gives me error that I do not have rights to edit them. Please help I need to get the files in the remote repo into the git bash.

Comment: what do you mean by "my git bash can't recognize that it is my account"? did you `ssh-add` before trying to pull from your repo?

Answer (score 1):

When you changed your username, the URL to the repository changed as well. When you now try to push, it is pushing to a repository that does not exist anymore.

The way to fix this is to point your local repository to the correct remote one:

```
git remote rename origin origin-backup
git remote add origin <git@github.com/new-username/repository>
```

Afterwards, you should be able to push again.